# SQL Report modeling - Adding an additional attribute to the report model

Tags: sql, database, model, report

Trying to find out how significant of a change it would be to include ONE additional attribute to an existing report model that provides reporting in a business intelligence(Business Objects)space. Seems pretty easy but i'm being told it would require a significant change, which I think is bs.

Thanks.

Comment: mind providing some details and context?

Comment: If you can define *easy* and *significant* with examples from your context, we can offer suggestions.

Comment: We use business objects for all our reporting needs. I'm not sure if the reports are run from model designer, development studio or report manager. I assume its its pulling date from views which are built on top of an sql server. The database is not big, attributes sit from around 1-1000 and there are about 50-100 tables. Not sure what else I can provide but that is about all the info I have.